# How to fix UI deadlock on async WMI select/PerformanceCounter for getting remote machine LastBootUpTime

Tags: c#, asynchronous, wmi, deadlock, performancecounter

I'm just creating Form aplication for controling remote workstations and servers on our company network and I have to create "Wait on restart of remote machine" function. This function is OK, but I need it to run asynchoniously and there is my problem... 
The function check firstly online/offline status to determine restart and after that it is check new LastBootUpTime value of remote machine to be sure it was really restart and not only network problem. 
When I run this check asynchroniously, ManagementObjectSearcher trigger deadlock, when using it's .Get() method. The same problem I have when I use PerformanceCounter instead.

There is 3 main objects for this:
1) Form class
2) Relation class (owned by Form)
3) RestartChecker class (owned by Relation)

When RestartChecker get info that restart was made, sends this info trough event to Relation. Relation use it's own event to sends it to Form and Form change icon on UI.

Here is my code (important parts) from RestartChecker:

This method is in Relation class and it's starts the RestartChecker. This Relation method is called from Form class.

```
    public void StartRestartMonitoring()
    {
        restartChecker = new RestartChecker(machine.Name, machine.OperatingSystem.lastBootUpTime.Value, wmiSuccess);

        //WasRestarted property calls event on value change to true. That event change icons on Form
        restartChecker.RestartWasMade += new Action(() => { WasRestarted = true; }); 

        restartChecker.Start();
    }
```

This method starts the check for restart function

```
Task checker;
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;   

    public void Start()
    {
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

        checker = CheckActionAsync(token);
        running = true;
    }
```

This is the more important part => Task method which should run asynchoniously

```
    private async Task CheckActionAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        bool isOnline = await RemoteTask.PingAsync(target, PING_TIMEOUT_SECONDS);
        int onlineState = (isOnline) ? 0 : 1;

        try
        {
            lastKnownBootUpTime = (isOnline) ? (GetLastBootUpTime(target, useWMI) ?? lastKnownBootUpTime) : lastKnownBootUpTime;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Logs to File
            EventNotifier.Log(ex,....);
        }

        //This part looks OK...
            while (onlineState < 2)
            {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }

                bool actualOnlineState = await RemoteTask.PingAsync(target, PING_TIMEOUT_SECONDS);
                onlineState += (actualOnlineState == isOnline) ? 0 : 1;

                await Task.Delay(CHECK_INTERVAL);
            }

        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }

            //Here, until I get properly value for LastBootUpTime of remote machine, I'm still trying again and again (beacause first try is cannot be OK => machine is Online, but services for WMI is not ready yet, so there is exception on first try)
            while (newBootUpTime == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    newBootUpTime = GetLastBootUpTime(target, useWMI);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Some reactions to exception including logging to File
                }

                await Task.Delay(INTERVAL);
            }

            //This part looks ok too..
            newBootUpTime = newBootUpTime.Value.AddTicks(-newBootUpTime.Value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
            lastKnownBootUpTime = lastKnownBootUpTime.Value.AddTicks(-lastKnownBootUpTime.Value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);

            if (newBootUpTime.Value > lastKnownBootUpTime.Value)
            {
                RestartWasMade?.Invoke();
                return;
            }

            await Task.Delay(CHECK_INTERVAL);
        }
    }
```

GetLastBoostUpTime method

```
    private static DateTime? GetLastBootUpTime(string target, bool useWMI)
    {
        DateTime? lastBootUpTime = null;

        if (useWMI)
        {
            //wmiBootUpTime is SelectQuery
            string dateInString = RemoteTask.SelectStringsFromWMI(wmiBootUpTime, new ManagementScope(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", target))).First()[wmiBootUpTime.SelectedProperties[0].ToString()];
            lastBootUpTime = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateInString)) ? null : (DateTime?)ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(dateInString);
        }
        else
        {
            TimeSpan? osRunningTime = RemoteTask.GetUpTime(target);
            lastBootUpTime = (osRunningTime == null) ? null : (DateTime?)DateTime.Now.Subtract(osRunningTime.Value);
        }

        return lastBootUpTime;
    }
```

WMI method used for getting the data:

```
    public static List<Dictionary<string, string>> SelectStringsFromWMI(SelectQuery select, ManagementScope wmiScope)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> result = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, select))
        {
            //This line is deadlock-maker... Because remote machine  services is not ready yet, searcher.Get() is trying
            //until reach it's timeout (by default it is 30s) and that's my deadlock. For the time of running searcher.Get()
            //there is 30s deadlock. Where is the mistake I've made? I supposed that this can not confront my UI thread
            using (ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in objectCollection)
                {
                    result.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
                    foreach (PropertyData property in managementObject.Properties)
                    {
                        result.Last().Add(property.Name, property.Value?.ToString());
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

PerformanceCounte method used for getting the data:

```
    public static TimeSpan? GetUpTime(string remoteMachine = null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (PerformanceCounter upTime = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteMachine))
                ? new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time")
                : new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time", null, remoteMachine))
            {
                upTime.NextValue();
                return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(upTime.NextValue());
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Asynchronious ping method

```
    public async static Task<bool> PingAsync(string target, int pingTimeOut)
    {
        bool result = false;
        Exception error = null;

        using (Ping pinger = new Ping())
        {
            try
            {
                PingReply replay = await pinger.SendPingAsync(target, pingTimeOut * 1000);
                result = (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success) ? true : false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error = ex;
            }
        }

        if (error != null) { throw error; }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see deadlock here, but I see you block async method with sync call

`newBootUpTime = GetLastBootUpTime(target, useWMI);`

you can should call this in separate thread asynchronously I think or make GetLastBootUpTime method async

`newBootUpTime = await Task.Run(() => GetLastBootUpTime(target, useWMI));`

You also should remove all other sync blocking calls from your async methods using way above..

Deadlock may cause only if you call

`checker.Wait();` somewhere in thread in which you created `Task checker` (UI thread probably)

Are you doing this?

Also you can read about what is deadlock and how to avoid it here

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Thank you for respond. No, I'm not using .Wait() anywehere, so it's must be true that GetLastBootUpTime() have to block thread somehow. But even when I'm using your suggested code - await Task.Run(() => ... problem persist

Comment: @Blaato Then I assume the problem in another code you did not provide...

Comment: @Blaato can you provide additional code and\or all references to `Task checker` in code?

Comment: Yes of course, I edited the question and now I believe there is all important code parts.

Comment: @Blaato you still have blocking sync `GetLastBootUpTime` call in async method:
`lastKnownBootUpTime = (isOnline) ? (GetLastBootUpTime(target, useWMI) ?? lastKnownBootUpTime) : lastKnownBootUpTime;`
Try to run it via await Task.Run(()... too.
In my opinion you don't have a deadlock, but you have sync blocking calls in your async methods..

Comment: also probably you should have `throw` after `EventNotifier.Log(ex,....);`

Comment: Well, now (after edit calling of `GetLastBootUpTime`) everything seems to be OK, thank you. Once I saw a little sync blocking, but I believe that the case is sync File logging.
But last question.. Why should I put `throw` after exception logging? I don't want to throw this exception, it is not important for this function. All I want is log it.

Comment: @Blaato it was just assumption, if you know that you doing it is fine